# Change the versionCode in android manifest in python and save back the file

Tags: android, python, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I am trying to automate changing my VersionCode to match the build number of SVN. I am using python to parse the Android Manifest and trying to save the file back.

I am using Element tree to find the particular node this way

```
def setVersionCode(fileName,versionCode):
    ET.register_namespace("android", "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android")
    tree = ET.ElementTree() 
    tree.parse(fileName)
    root = tree.getroot() #This returns the root node
    root.attrib["{http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android}versionCode] " #This gives me the current Version code
```

And then calling it like this

```
setVersionCode(pathToTheManifest,"500")
```

I want to set the versionCode to 500 (example) and save the file back to the same fileName path without losing any Manifest formatting or xml data.
How do I do this ?

I know this works

```
 root.attrib["{http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android}versionCode] " = versionCode
```

because when I do a ET.dump it shows me the changed file. But how do I save it back to the same place from here without losing data or format?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the write method

```
def setVersionCode(fileName,versionCode):
    ET.register_namespace('android', 'http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android')
    tree = ET.parse(fileName)
    root = tree.getroot();
    root.attrib["{http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android}versionCode"] = versionCode
    tree.write(fileName)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good 3 years old now, I don't work where I had this problem :) But might be a working answer , so Ill just leave it here